# Why cant I see my created tables in oracle SQL developers tables tab?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can run SQL statements but cant find the tables in the "tables" tab.
How can I solve this?
For example, the EMP table is not showing in Tables tab.
Also, how to create a new database? I am MS SQL server background.
[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you mean "I can run SQL statements" not "can't".  What user are you logged in as?  Are you logged in as `AIUB`?  It appears that you are not.  It appears that you are, perhaps, logged in as `SYS`.

Comment: SQL Developer can't be used to create a new database - assuming you're not on 12c with Multitenant.

Are you sure you want a new database, and not just a new schema? You can create a new user/schema in your existing database if you open the DBA panel and check out the Security, Users tree node. Right click and create a new user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be two possibilities -

1. As Justin Cave commented, you might not be logged in as the AIUB user. Do, `SHOW USER`, if it is not the user AIUB, then DISCONNECT and log in as AIUB user.
2. FILTER might have been applied in SQL Developer for TABLES. Try Clear filter option.

Do not use SYS, it is special and not for regular use.

- Never ever use SYS (or SYSDBA) but for maintenance purpose (startup, shutdown, backup, recover)
- SYS/SYSDBA is special
- SYS/SYSDBA is Oracle proprietary (try to open a SR/TAR starting with "i did that with SYS/SYSDBA" and you'll see the immediate answer)
- SYS/SYSDBA does not act like any other user
- When you use SYS/SYSDBA Oracle deactivates some code path and activates others
- Whatever you do with SYS/SYSDBA will neither validate nor invalidate the same thing with any other user.

NEVER EVER use SYS/SYSDBA for anything that can be done by another user. 
Use SYS/SYSDBA ONLY for something that can't be done by someone else. Read http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/164126/0/